# Create a dataframe for stock analysis using a datetimeindex timeseries data source

Tags: python, pandas, finance, stock

I have a datasource which gives me the following dataframe, `pricehistory`:

```
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------+
|         time        |   close    |    high    |    low     |    open    |  volume  | red  |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------+
|                     |            |            |            |            |          |      |
| 2020-01-02 10:14:00 | 321.336177 | 321.505186 | 321.286468 | 321.505186 | 311601.0 | True |
| 2020-01-02 11:16:00 | 321.430623 | 321.465419 | 321.395827 | 321.465419 | 42678.0  | True |
| 2020-01-02 11:17:00 | 321.425652 | 321.445536 | 321.375944 | 321.440565 | 39827.0  | True |
| 2020-01-02 11:33:00 | 321.137343 | 321.261614 | 321.137343 | 321.261614 | 102805.0 | True |
| 2020-01-02 12:11:00 | 321.256643 | 321.266585 | 321.241731 | 321.266585 | 25629.0  | True |
| 2020-01-02 12:12:00 | 321.246701 | 321.266585 | 321.231789 | 321.266585 | 40869.0  | True |
| 2020-01-02 13:26:00 | 321.226818 | 321.266585 | 321.226818 | 321.261614 | 44011.0  | True |
| 2020-01-03 10:18:00 | 320.839091 | 320.958392 | 320.828155 | 320.958392 | 103351.0 | True |
| 2020-01-03 10:49:00 | 320.988217 | 321.077692 | 320.988217 | 321.057809 | 84492.0  | True |
| etc...              | etc...     | etc...     | etc...     | etc...     | etc...   | etc. |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+----------+------+
```

Output of `pricehistory.dtypes`:

```
close     float64
high      float64
low       float64
open      float64
volume    float64
red          bool
dtype: object
```

Output of `pricehistory.index.dtype`:
`dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Note: This dataframe is large, each row is 1-min of data and spans for months, so there are many time frames to iterate over.

#### Question:

I have some specific criteria I'd like to use that will become columns in a new dataframe:

1. High price and time (minute) of each day for the entire dataframe
2. The first occurrence of 4 downward trending minutes `open < close` during the day with their respective times

So far, I'm not exactly sure how to pull the time (datetimeindex value) and high price from `pricehistory`.

For (1) above, I'm using `pd.DataFrame(pricehistory.high.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).max())` which gives me:

```
+------------+------------+
|    time    |    high    |
+------------+------------+
|            |            |
| 2020-01-02 | 322.956677 |
| 2020-01-03 | 321.753729 |
| 2020-01-04 | NaN        |
| 2020-01-05 | NaN        |
| 2020-01-06 | 321.843204 |
| etc...     | etc...     |
+------------+------------+
```

But this doesn't work because it's only giving me the day and not down to the minute, and using `min` as the `Grouper` freq doesn't work because then it's just the max value of each min, which is `high`.

#### Desired outcome (note: minutes included):

```
+---------------------+------------+
|    time             |    high    |
+---------------------+------------+
|                     |            |
| 2020-01-02 9:31:00  | 322.956677 |
| 2020-01-03 10:13:11 | 321.753729 |
| 2020-01-04 15:33:12 | 320.991231 |
| 2020-01-06 12:01:23 | 321.843204 |
| etc...              | etc...     |
+---------------------+------------+
```

For (2) above, I'm using the following:

`pricehistory['red'] = pricehistory['close'].lt(pricehistory['open'])`

To make a new column in `pricehistory` which shows us if there are 4 red minutes in a row.

Then, using `new_pricehistory = pricehistory.loc[pricehistory[::-1].rolling(4)['red'].sum().eq(4)]`, this gives a new dataframe of only the rows where 4 red minutes in a row occur, preferably I'd like to only have the very first occurrence, not all.

Current output:

```
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
|        time         |   close    |    high    |    low     |    open    | volume | red  |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
|                     |            |            |            |            |        |      |
| 2020-01-02 10:14:00 | 321.336177 | 321.505186 | 321.286468 | 321.505186 | 311601 | TRUE |
| 2020-01-03 10:18:00 | 320.839091 | 320.958392 | 320.828155 | 320.958392 | 103351 | TRUE |
| 2020-01-06 10:49:00 | 320.520956 | 320.570665 | 320.501073 | 320.550781 |  71901 | TRUE |
+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve) and have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @rpanai I'm not sure how to make this any more clear and specific, what do you need help understanding?

Comment: The problem is easy to understand but it will be nice if you provide some data. You'll even increase your chances to get answers.

Comment: Updated with some examples

Comment: Are you looking for exactly 4 straight red or at least 4?

Comment: The first occurrence during each day of 4 straight red

Comment: Added a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Given you didn't provide data I create some dummy one. By SO policy you should make different question per problem. For now I'm answering the first one.

## Generate data

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

times = pd.date_range(start="2020-06-01", end="2020-06-10", freq="1T")
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":times,
                  "high":np.random.randn(len(times))})
```

## Question 1

Here I just look for index where the maximum per day occour and filter `df` accordingly

```py
idx = df.groupby(df["time"].dt.date)["high"].idxmax().values

df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

**Update:**  In case you have time as index in your df the solution will be

```py
df = df.set_index("time")

idx = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))["high"].idxmax().values
df[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

## Question 2

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# generate data
times = pd.date_range(start="2020-06-01", end="2020-06-10", freq="1T")
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":times,
                   "open":np.random.randn(len(times))})

df["open"] = np.where(df["open"]<0, -1 * df["open"], df["open"])
df["close"] = df["open"] + 0.01 *np.random.randn(len(times))
df = df.set_index("time")
df["red"] = df['close'].lt(df['open'])

# this function return the first time 
# when there are 4 consecutive red

def get_first(ts):
    idx = ts.loc[ts[::-1].rolling(4)['red'].sum().ge(4)].index
    if idx.empty:
        return pd.NaT
    else:
        return idx[0]

# get first time within group and drop nan
grp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))\
        .apply(get_first).dropna()



df[df.index.isin(grp.values)]
```

Comment: The data is all listed above, I'm using a dataframe called `pricehistory` and it's format is given, the index is a `datetimeindex` which includes all days/times, not like yours that has an integer index and a column of times.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you didn't provide any sample data. In any case it's trivial to convert a dataframe to look as yours and the solution still stands.

Comment: The sample data is the initial table given above, and your solution is not sufficient as it's a completely different type of index

Comment: The sample data you provide contains a single row only. Anyway I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updates - I'm not sure why, but for #1, I'm getting a `ValueError` with no specific traceback when using that code, I don't think `idxmax()` works on the `groupby`?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? Is time a daytime dtype for you?

Comment: Pandas 0.25.3. My index is `<M8[ns]` datetimeindex

Comment: @afrotaint it works for me on pandas 1.03 and 0.24.1 Any chance you could share your actual df?

Comment: updated with specifics on dataframe, can move to chat also